# properties with the same name and different type in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can I have a property and a method with the same names and different types in an object like below in JavaScript?

```
var o = {};
o.sample = {
  x : 10,
  y : 20 }

o.sample = function() {
  return this.sample.x + this.sample.y
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't, the `sample` method overrides the `sample` property.

Comment: if I can't, how can I do some thing like this?